# Can I use SLI with a GTX 560Ti and a GTX 260+?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I am trying to find out if I can SLI my MSI GTX 560Ti with my Zotac GTX 260+?

Is that possible or would it get too hot, or not work at all? Will it function correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SLi requires that you have identical chips on both the GPUs, so this isn't possible.

Even if it was, you're effectively making your GTX560 run as slow as GTX260+, negating any performance benefits that you might get

Answer (score 6):

To complement Sathya's answer, **no** you won't be able to run your cards in **SLI** as the GPU's are not identical.  The difference in manufacturers should not make a difference.

*However*, you **should** be able to have both connected and have your GTX260 work as a **dedicated PhysX processor**.  As usual, you should make sure you have adequate cooling in either configuration.  Both cards are likely to generate the same amount of heat as they would alone (while the card designated for PhysX use may be reduced overall) so you need to account for that.

From the [PhysX FAQ](http://www.nvidia.com/object/physx_faq.html):

> **How does PhysX work with SLI and multi-GPU configurations?**
>   ...
>
> A new configuration that’s now possible with PhysX is 2 non-matched (heterogeneous) GPUs. In this configuration, one GPU renders graphics (typically the more powerful GPU) while the second GPU is completely dedicated to PhysX. By offloading PhysX to a dedicated GPU, users will experience smoother gaming.
>
> ...

I'd take advantage of this configuration that way you can use your GTX560 to its fullest potential and not be bogged down just because you want to enable PhysX (provided you have an adequate cooling solution).